# GIF not animating on page load

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, gif

I am trying to create a splash page (I know, I tried to talk him out of it) that displays the logo animation (.gif) and a button to enter website. So far, I have a `div` that contains the image, however, the image is not animating as one would expect. Surprisingly, the image animates every time in Internet Explorer. How do I go about solving this?

I have tried injecting the image after page load with jQuery to no avail.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#splash").append("<img src='img/logo_splash.gif'>");
})
```

Comment: You say it animates in IE. What browser doesn't it animate in?

Comment: All other browsers except IE. Chrome, Firefox, Opera.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce it in a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Pjcst/ It is working here for some reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try appending a random number to your GIF URL. Chrome and Firefox prevent a GIF from playing more than once.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#splash").append("<img src='img/logo_splash.gif?"+ Math.random() + "'/>");
})
```

Comment: The image doesn't loads at all.

Comment: Flawless! It's working. Any idea why browsers prevent GIF from playing more than once?

Comment: Yes, because they are annoying :-)

Comment: @Rafay: Can you please share your final code via which you were able to run your gif. I am facing a similar kind of problem ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45377718/gif-wont-load-in-safari-but-runs-in-chrome)) while trying to load GIF in Safari.