# GIF not moving when referenced in my HTML code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gif

What I'm trying to do is to display a process bar when a user clicks on submit. the gifs works if I just open it in my web browser but when I add a reference to it in my HTML code it doesn't work. My dialog appears with the GIF but the gif doesn't move. Here is my code:

```
<div id="progressDialog" title="Importing Welcome Kit Rules" style="display: none;">
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/AjaxProgress.gif")" alt="Processing" />
    <p>Please wait while your request is processed.</p> 
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Hide the "busy" Gif at load:
    if ($('#progressDialog').dialog('isOpen')) {
        $('#progressDialog').dialog('close');
    }

    // Handle the form submit event, and make the Ajax request:
    $("#myform").on("submit", function (event) {
        // Show the "busy" Gif:
        $("#progressDialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            bgiframe: true
        });

        $('#progressDialog').dialog('open');
    });
});
```

Comment: what browser are you using? I believe there is a problem with JQuery, gifs, and IE.

Comment: IIRC animated gifs stop moving when a page load is initiated (new page is loading, form is submitting etc.).

Comment: I found a similar question to yours hopefully this helps 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/24595410/620723